# Inserting into another seperate line with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Insert Input into New Line

```
'Set the ini Path'
Dim iniPath As String = "settings.ini"
'Set Text into ini File
Dim settings As String = TextBox2.Text
'Appends New Line to the settings file
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(iniPath, settings, True)
```

At this point I want the settings to break into a new line when it's put into the settings file. For instance; if I put Setting1 into the file and then I put setting 2 into the file at another time it's going to produce
`Setting1Setting 2`

Where I want it to produce

```
Setting1
Setting 2
```

Does anybody know how I can do this in Visual Basic 2010?
A little bit of clarification:

So In the project you have the option to add an application configuration file which then shows itself as settings.config. I want this to be able to be edited by a textbox for instance; 
TextBox2.Text=ServerIP.Text
So that when they click on TextBox2.Text and enter 192.168.1.12 and then click save it will write 192.168.1.12 into their configuration as a saved IP and they can pull it up at a later time and switch between.
Hopefully that makes a little more sense to anyone who might have any ideas.

Comment: Hard to decode this question.  Sounds to me like you forgot to set the Multiline property of the TextBox to True.

Comment: Hard to decode this question. Sounds like you need to rephrase it to be more clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to find a way to split up each setting from the `TextBox2.Text` and then add a `VbCrLf` in between them. Try this to see how it works:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(iniPath, "Setting1" & VbCrLf & "Setting 2", True)
```